# Where to put 2nd jQuery.ajax function and isset() checking of the POST variable?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

This is a page using a single `jQuery.ajax` posting to the same page and is working fine.

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_POST['varA'])) {
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(bingo);

            function bingo()
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data:  {varA: "123"},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("#test").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="test"></span>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
else 
{
    print_r($_POST['varA']);
}
?>
```

**Situation:** I have another variable that I wish to set using another separate `jQuery.ajax`.  However, my page content duplicated itself when I put them altogether like this.

**Bad Example** (depicting what I'm trying to do)

```
<?php 
    if (!isset($_POST['varA'])) {
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(bingo);

                function bingo()
                {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data:  {varA: "123"},
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $("#test").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }

                function buttony() //added 2nd independent jQuery.ajax function
                {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {varB: "456"},
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $("#test2").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <span id="test"></span>
            <span id="test2"</span> //added 2nd span
            <input type="button" value="Clicky" onclick="buttony()"/> //added
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    }
    else 
    {
        print_r($_POST['varA']);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['varB'])) //added isset() checking
    {
        print_r($_POST['varB']);
        echo 'varB Okay';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'varB Not';
    }
?>
```

**Additional information**: Posting of variables for both `jQuery.ajax` of "Bad Example" are working fine.

---

**Note:** Pictures below are not from the codes above, just an example of what I meant by "content duplicated itself".

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

---

**Question:** May I know where should I put my 2nd `jQuery.ajax` function and `isset()` checking of the POST variable, in such a way that both `jQuery.ajax` functions will work correctly and won't conflict with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `window.location` to replace the use of 2nd jQuery.ajax to avoid complication.

**Sample example**

Inside JavaScript function

```
window.location = "samePage.php?varB=abc";
```

Checking of POST variable varB

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['varB'])
{
    $getValue = $_REQUEST['varB'];
}
```

I'm leaving the question open for the community to tackle on how to do proper nesting of using 2 or more `jQuery.ajax` in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to pass the bingo function the document ready function. Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            function bingo()
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data:  {varA: "123"},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("#test").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }

            bingo();

            function buttony() //added 2nd independent jQuery.ajax function
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {varB: "456"},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("#test2").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }

            buttony();

}); //end document ready
```

Comment: bingo() should execute once when document is ready but buttony() is not. That is also not the problem but thank you for your interest.